# Is 'desc' a valid name for a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

If I try to create a table called test with one column, it works:

```
mysql> create table test(surname VARCHAR(300));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> drop table test;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But if I try now to create the same table, but this time the column is called 'desc' instead of 'surname', I get an error:

```
mysql> create table test(desc VARCHAR(300));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc VARCHAR(300))' at line 1
mysql>
```

What am I getting wrong here? Is 'desc' a reserved keyword in mysql?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ASC" or "DESC" are the reserved keyword in MySQL. you can't use it for column name. "ASC/DESC" is the keyword used to sort result sets in either ascending or descending order. "ASC" is used as the default.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned already, "desc" is a **reserved word** in MySQL used to dictate sorting in the `ORDER BY` clause, so you should avoid naming things with it. But if you really must, then you can use backticks around the name `` `desc` `` as per this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446378/5059085) which has a lot of information on **reserved words** in MySQL.